# (Java) How to read/write Text in/out of a Textfield/Textarea/Textlabel/... of another Programm

Tags: java, user-interface, text

I was trying to make a easy Bot (Java) for the Skypechat or something like this. I want it to read the text which was sent to me at least and calculate by a clever progress a good answer. This answer should be written back of course. And here comes my problem.

I have no idea, how to read the Text *(if it is easier to do, read the whole one, but just the last message would be better)* of the unknown Textarea/Textfield/whatever and write mine back into the Textbox of my Client.
Also, it would be nice to know, how to make my Bot "pressing the sendbutton". I´ve seen such a Bot, already.
The Progress which is creating the answer exists already, so you dont have to care for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably have to implement a Skype add-on/app that would interface with your application. I do not think java will be able to interface with the Skype window in an at all easy way, if at all.

There is an Skype-Java API available which can be found here, nto sure how good it is, but you may be able to get it to work: http://half-wit4u.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/skype-using-java-api-skype4java.html